# Unable to connect to Postgres on EC2: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sequelize.js

I have a Node server hosted on an EC2 instance that is trying to connect to Postgres running on the same instance. When I start the server I get an ECONNREFUSED error to the db:

`Unable to connect to the database: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED x.x.x.x:5432`

I am using the Sequelize ORM package from NPM:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const db = new Sequelize('postgres://postgres@52.9.136.53/unloadx' {dialect: 'postgres'});
```

Postgres is running on the instance, and I have port 5432 open in my inbound security rule. I can confirm that postgres is running with `ps aux | grep postgres` which shows multiple postgres related processes, and `netstat -anp --tcp` confirms that postgres appears to be listening on the port:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

But when I scan the port with `nmap x.x.x.x -p 5432` it shows that the port status is closed. Per nmap, this means that the port is accessible but has no application listening on it able to respond to packets.

Appreciate any help in getting the connection to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are using the public IP address. That means your database connection is basically going out to the internet and back. This will prevent the Security Group rule from working, and introduce security and latency issues.

If you were trying to connect from another server in the VPC you would want to connect using the private IP. However, since it's on the same instance you can delete the Security Group rule and just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: That was it, thanks. FWIW 'localhost' worked but not 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that `netstat` is showing that postgres is listening on the port?  If it were, you'd see something in the PID/Program column.

Also, if your postgres server is running on the same box as your node app, you should not need to open up the port to the internet via your AWS security rules, and probably shouldn't unless you need to access it from elsewhere. Then you can change your connection string to hit localhost or 127.0.0.1

Finally, verify that you've setup your postgres server correctly via the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)

Comment: Good point - it is weird that postgres does not show in the program name column. But since there is a process on the default postgres port, and since the above fix of changing the public IP to localhost appears to have worked the unnamed process does appear to be for postgres